# Use method of characteristics, find a parametric representation of a shock equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$h(r,t)$

PDE: $${h_t} + r(h^2){h_r} = -\frac{2}{3}h^3$$ in $r\ge 0$, $t\ge 0$,

h bounded at $r=0$ for all $t$.

Initial condition:

$h(r,0) = 1-r$ if $0 \le r \le 1$

$h(r,0) = 0$ elsewhere

i) using method of characteristics, find a parametric representation for the solution to the PDE with the initial condition stated above.

ii) Calculate $h(0,t)$ for all $t$.

iii) Show that the solution $h(r,t)$ becomes multi-valued for the first time at $$t = {t_b} = \frac{10}{3}$$

The answer to i) is

$$h(s,t) = \frac{1-s}{(1+\frac{4t}{3}(1-s)^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$$ for $0 \le s \le 1$

how do I get that answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a quick answer (not the complete solving of the PDE) only to see where the answer i) comes from :

You should have given the notations you use for the variables in the characteristics equations. The symbols used below are probably different, which might be confusing.

[image]

If you need more explanation, ask someone else. I will not be here for a long time.